# Getting speed improvement with OpenMP in nested for loops with dependencies

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to implement a procedure in parallel processing form with OpenMP. It contains four level nested for loops (dependent) and has a variable `sum_p` to be updated in the innermost loop. In short, the my question is regarding the parallel implementation of the following code snippet:

```
for (int i = (test_map.size() - 1); i >= 1; --i) {
     bin_i = test_map.at(i); //test_map is a "STL map of vectors"
     len_rank_bin_i = bin_i.size(); // bin_i is a vector
     for (int j = (i - 1); j >= 0; --j) {
             bin_j = test_map.at(j);
             len_rank_bin_j = bin_j.size();
             for (int u_i = 0; u_i < len_rank_bin_i; u_i++) {
                     node_u = bin_i[u_i]; //node_u is a scalar
                     for (int v_i = 0; v_i < len_rank_bin_j; v_i++) {
                             node_v = bin_j[v_i];
                             if (node_u> node_v)
                                     sum_p += 1;
                     }
             }
     }
}
```

The full program is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    double time_temp;
    int test_map_size = 5000;
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> > test_map(test_map_size);

    // Fill the test map with random intergers ---------------------------------
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen1(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 5);
    auto gen = std::bind(dist, gen1);
    for(int i = 0; i < test_map_size; i++)
    {
        int vector_len = dist(gen1);
        std::vector<unsigned int> tt(vector_len);
        std::generate(begin(tt), end(tt), gen);
        test_map.insert({i,tt});
    }
    // Sequential implementation -----------------------------------------------
    time_temp = omp_get_wtime();
    std::vector<unsigned int> bin_i, bin_j;
    unsigned int node_v, node_u;
    unsigned int len_rank_bin_i;
    unsigned int len_rank_bin_j;
    int sum_s = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = (test_map_size - 1); i >= 1; --i) {
        bin_i = test_map.at(i);
        len_rank_bin_i = bin_i.size();
        for (unsigned int j = i; j-- > 0; ) {
            bin_j = test_map.at(j);
            len_rank_bin_j = bin_j.size();
            for (unsigned int u_i = 0; u_i < len_rank_bin_i; u_i++) {
                node_u = bin_i[u_i];
                for (unsigned int v_i = 0; v_i < len_rank_bin_j; v_i++) {
                    node_v = bin_j[v_i];
                    if (node_u> node_v)
                        sum_s += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Estimated sum (seq): "<<sum_s<<std::endl;
    time_temp = omp_get_wtime() - time_temp;
    printf("Time taken for sequential implementation: %.2fs\n", time_temp);

    // Parallel implementation -----------------------------------------------
    time_temp = omp_get_wtime();
    int sum_p = 0;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::vector<unsigned int> bin_i, bin_j;
        unsigned int node_v, node_u;
        unsigned int len_rank_bin_i;
        unsigned int len_rank_bin_j;
        unsigned int i, u_i, v_i;
        int j;
        #pragma omp parallel for private(j,u_i,v_i) reduction(+:sum_p)
        for (i = (test_map_size - 1); i >= 1; --i) {
            bin_i = test_map.at(i);
            len_rank_bin_i = bin_i.size();
            #pragma omp parallel for private(u_i,v_i)
            for (j = (i - 1); j >= 0; --j) {
                bin_j = test_map.at(j);
                len_rank_bin_j = bin_j.size();
                #pragma omp parallel for private(v_i)
                for (u_i = 0; u_i < len_rank_bin_i; u_i++) {
                    node_u = bin_i[u_i];
                    #pragma omp parallel for
                    for (v_i = 0; v_i < len_rank_bin_j; v_i++) {
                        node_v = bin_j[v_i];
                        if (node_u> node_v)
                            sum_p += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Estimated sum (parallel): "<<sum_p<<std::endl;
    time_temp = omp_get_wtime() - time_temp;
    printf("Time taken for parallel implementation: %.2fs\n", time_temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code with command `g++-7 -fopenmp -std=c++11 -O3  -Wall  -o so_qn so_qn.cpp` in macOS 10.13.3 (i5 processor with four logical cores) gives the following output:

```
Estimated sum (seq): 38445750
Time taken for sequential implementation: 0.49s
Estimated sum (parallel): 38445750
Time taken for parallel implementation: 50.54s
```

The time taken for parallel implementation is multiple times higher than sequential implementation. Do you think the code or logic can deduced to parallel implementation? I have spent a few days to improve the terrible performance of my code but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**
With the changes suggested by JimCownie, i.e., "using omp for, not omp parallel for" and removing the parellelism of inner loops, the performance is greatly improved.

```
Estimated sum (seq): 42392944
Time taken for sequential implementation: 0.48s
Estimated sum (parallel): 42392944
Time taken for parallel implementation: 0.27s
```

My CPU has four logical cores (and I am using four threads), now I am wondering, would there be anyway to get four times better performance than the sequential implementation.

I see a different problem here when my map of vectors `test_map` is short, but fat at each level, i.e., the map size is small and but the vector size at each of the keys is very large. In such a case the performance of sequential and parallel implementations are comparable, without much difference. It seems like we need to parallelize inner loops too. Do you know how to achieve it in this context?

Comment: Don't use `clock` to time OpenMP programs.  This issue has been covered in a number of Qs and As here on SO.  Use `omp_get_wtime`.

Comment: Also, compile with some optimisation (eg `-O2`) and give your program (a lot) more work to do.  Run some more tests.

Comment: You have misunderstood the scoping and sharing rules "The variables bin_i, b_j, node_v, node_u, len_rank_bin_i, len_rank_bin_j need to be inside #pragma omp parallel, otherwise the code run produces segmentation fault." What you need is to declare them in the closest scope possible. You are still sharing these. Also you have lots of unnecessary nested parallelism (which is what makes these variables still be incorrectly shared). You should be using omp for, not omp parallel for. If rank_new_len is big enough you probably don;'t need to try to parallelize the inner loops.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks! I have done all the changes you have suggested.

Comment: @JimCownie Thanks a lot! With the changes  "using omp for, not omp parallel for" and removing the parellelism of inner loops, the performance got reversed. Now I am getting two times better performance than sequential implementation with four threads (quad logical core CPU). Would there be anyway to get four times better performance than the sequential implementation?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. Here are some results. I have changed the `map` size (variable `test_map_size `) to 20,000 to make it run longer. With only one thread in the parallel implementation, time taken for sequential implementation is 8.11s, time taken for parallel implementation: 8.39s ! With four threads, for a different run it is 8.06s for sequential and 4.14s for parallel. I got your point, but the overhead of OpenMP doesn't seem to be the issue for longer runs. There seems to be something more. Thanks!

Comment: @JimCownie Regarding your other suggestions: 1. for the scope of the variables, whenever I try to declare them outside #pragma omp parellel block, I get segmentation fault (I have tried it just now). 2. " you have lots of unnecessary nested parallelism", and " If rank_new_len is big enough you probably don't need to try to parallelize the inner loops." It is, but can we get better performance with the inner loop parallelism? With your suggestion to use `#pragma omp for`, how do I achieve more parallelism including the inner loops? Using omp for in the inner loops gives compilation error.

Comment: @JimCownie. I see that removing `private` variables from the `#pragma omp for` is not causing any issue. But by including them, by making use of cache memory of each thread, is it supposed speed up the code? I do not see any difference in speed though.